# Configuration save failed in joomla 3.2

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

I'm developing component in Joomla 3.2 and having problem with saving configuration values to extension table.I've included the configuration values in config.xml.After installing my component,i would go to my configuration page and clicked save.It has updated successfully in extension table's params field for my extension.But when i installing component the configuration values should be update in extension table.Can you please help to solve this ?

Comment: Let's make it clear- you make a component on local machine. When you try to install it on different server/ or another repository/ site- error pops up. I understood you right?

Comment: No.wherever i installed the component(local or sever),1.installed the component.2.joomla created record in extension table.3.params field is empty.4.If go to component and select via option button.There all other component's configuration settings also available which comes from my component config.xml.(Its for joomla 3.2).5.Then i save the configuration.6.Now checking again the __extension table's params field.It has updated..The field has updated after saving manunally.But i want to update the params field in __extension table when installing my component.Have you got my doubt ?

Comment: So problem is only in first db table update (because in future user'll be clicking on button to save changes and the table'll be updated too), right?

Comment: Do it during post flight. Also you should always build in defaults in your component when getting parameters.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Managing_Component_Updates_%28Script.php%29

Comment: Its working.Now i can use in post flight.